# how to access a javascript variable declared in another javascript page

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my First Javascript File where I have declared a variable

```
$(document).ready(function (){

  $x=0;

});
```

This is my Second Javascript File

```
$(document).ready(function (){

 console.log($x);
```

});

But When i use the above code i get the output as undefined ...Can someone suggest me how to access the variable defined in other files.

Comment: @Satpal — It already is in the global scope. (And don't hide answers in comments).

Comment: @Satpal it should be defined globally if set like this. But there is an error in the above code. It should be `.ready(function() {}) ` instead of `.ready(function({})`

Comment: sorry it was jus a mistake here in my working file the code in fine .. i have edited my question also kindly have a look at it !! @Dieterg

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

> ```
> $(document).ready(function ({
> ```

You missed the `)` after `function (`.

Your first script therefore errors and `$x` is never set.

Comment: sorry it was jus a mistake here in my working file the code in fine .. i have edited my question also kindly have a look at it !! @quentin

Comment: @Dilkush — After your edit, I can no longer reproduce your problem: http://jsbin.com/mavese/1/edit?html,console

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code, it should be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $0 = 0
});
```

Also the order is important, your second file should load after this one

Comment: sorry it was jus a mistake here in my working file the code in fine .. i have edited my question also kindly have a look at it !!! And My Other is Fine the second file is the last file @dieterg

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the variable out of document ready

```
   $0 = 0;
   $(document).ready(function(){
       .....
   });
```

Comment: try accessing var like console.log(window.$0);